# How to call a function with an argument after the submitting button in the popup window was clicked?

Tags: reactjs, components

In React I created a component that holds a local state of popup. With a little help from onClick handler I change the local state to make the popup show up. The Popup component in turn contains confirm button. I would like to call a function deleteItem ONLY after the confirm button is clicked. But I don't get how to do it. In the code below the item gets deleted right after the popup shows up but it has to be deleted only if I press the button in the Popup component. If I understand correctely, the state of the components changes when the popup shows up and I have to get it khow to the MainComponent and only in this case the function deleteItem will be called.

```
import {deleteItem} from './item-reducer';

const MainComponent = ({items}) => {
 const [visiblePopup, setVisiblePopup] = useState(false);
    return( 
       {items.map(item => <li key={item.id}></li>
       <img onClick={() => {
         setVisiblePopup(true);
         deleteList(item.id) // I have to call this function after the button 
         in the Popup component is pressed
        }}
       />
    )}
   <Popup setVisiblePopup={setVisiblePopup}
  )
}

Popup.jsx
<div onClick={() => setVisiblePopup(false)} /> 
    Confirm
</div>
```

What I have to accomplish 1) I click img and popup shows up 2) I press
'Confirm' 3) function deleteItem is invoked 4)popup dissapeares.

Comment: `onClick={ () => { setVisiblePopUp(true); deleteList(item.id); } }` should do your case, you have just missed a curly bracket in wrong place =)

Comment: @Halil Cakar Thanks, I fixed it. But it isn't the case. I mean, I should  deleteList(item.id) ONLY after the button in thePopup is clicked.

Comment: @brad_fresh use the square bracket syntax `onClick={() => [setVisiblePopup(true), deleteList(item.id)]`

Comment: Hi, please include ***all*** relevant code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example. I see no actions being dispatched to a store, no components connected to a store, nor how the Popup (not full, valid component code) relates to `MainComponent`. If `Popup` is a separate component it *can't* call `MainComponent`'s `setVisiblePopup` state updater function. We need more context.

Comment: @ Drew Reese Check it out now! I tried to add a wider description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly this is what your looking for ?

```js
const MainComponent = ({items}) => {
    const [modalState, setModalState] = useState({
        display: false,
        deleteItemId: undefined
    });

    const modalCallback = useCallback((deleteItemId)=>{
        deleteItem(deleteItemId)
        setModalState({ display: false, deleteItemId: undefined })
    },[])

    
    return( 
        <Fragment>
            {
                items.map(item => (
                    <Fragment>
                        <li key={item.id}></li>
                        <img onClick={() => setModalState({ display: true, deleteItemId: item.id })} />
                    </Fragment>
                ))
            }
            <PopupModal 
                visible={modalState.display} 
                deleteItemId={modalState.deleteItemId} 
                callback={modalCallback}
            />
        </Fragment>
    )
}


const PopupModal = ({ visible, deleteItemId, callback }) => {
    return (visible ? <div onClick={ () => callback(deleteItemId)}>Confirm</div> : null)
}
```

**--- OR ----**

```js
const MainComponent = ({items}) => {
    const [modalState, setModalState] = useState({
        display: false,
        deleteItemId: undefined
    });
    
    return( 
        <Fragment>
            {
                items.map(item => (
                    <Fragment>
                        <li key={item.id}></li>
                        <img onClick={() => setModalState({ display: true, deleteItemId: item.id })} />
                    </Fragment>
                ))
            }
            modalState.display ? <div onClick={() => [deleteList(modalState.deleteItemId), setModalState({display: false, deleteItemId: undefined}) ]}>Confirm</div> : null
        </Fragment>
    )
}
```

Comment: No. I made popup visible by adding a class with "classnames" . It's alright with popup then. What I need is to call a deleteList(item.id) only after I press the 'Confirm' button in the Popup. Now as it is I call this function not the way it shoul be, because items gets deleted before the popup shows up. It has to be 1)popup shows up 2)I press 'Confirm' 3) function deleteItem is called 4)popup dissapeares.

Comment: @brad_fresh just save the `item.id` to the state

Comment: You helped a lot! Thank you!